# Where is Jeff Changeley

Tags: tournament, live, casino

Does anyone know if Jeff Changeley is still alive?  I have not seen or heard anything about him since the espn special in the Monaco Classic where he took down J.J. Lynch in the final table in January... Is he in the hospital, etc.?

Comment: I hope you find him, but this is not the place for these types of information requests. Good luck.